# devenv.exe execute through jenkin's job doesn't work

Tags: jenkins, devenv

i am trying to execute devenv.exe through windows batch command plugin in Jenkins
but it keeps on executing and fails to launch the application.

**Console Output :**

```
**In progressConsole Output
Started by user anonymous
Building on master in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\TEMP\workspace
[workspace] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\hudson3900292017086958332.bat
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\TEMP\workspace>set DEVPATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\TEMP\workspace>set PATH=D:\app\nazopay\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin;D:\app\nazopay\product\11.2.0\client_1;C:\Program Files (x86)\Integrity\IntegrityClient10\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\cde\tools;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application;C:\MingW;C:\PROGRA~2\INTEGR~1\Toolkit\mksnt;%JAVA_HOME%;,;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23;,;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin;%CLASS_PATH%;,;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\lib;,;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\lib;;C:\Program Files (x86)\M**icrosoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE 

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\TEMP\workspace>devenv.exe
```

Answer (score 8):

**You must execute `devenv.com`.**

The `devenv.exe` always attempts to open GUI, even when commands are given, and it can't. The `devenv.com` has output directed to standard output and works fine from Jenkins.

**You also must pass arguments.**

Without arguments both `devenv.com` and `devenv.exe` just start the IDE GUI, which is not what you want. The correct command-line is

```
devenv.com projectname.sln /Build Release /Project projectname
```

First is path to the solution you want to build. Then the `/Build` flag is followed by configuration. If you have multiple platforms, you have to pass configuration and platform combination, e.g. `Release|Win32`. The `/Project` flag names project to build (including all dependencies). If omitted, it builds all projects selected for build in given configuration.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use msbuild?

This would be a good starting point for your windows build script:

```
call "%VS100COMNTOOLS%\vsvars32.bat"
msbuild projectname.sln /target:Rebuild /l:FileLogger,Microsoft.Build.Engine;logfile=msbuild.log || goto error
goto end
:error
@echo ERROR: Build failed
exit/b 1
:end
exit/b 0
```

This way you can also capture the output log that you can parse with one of the jenkins plugins.
Ofcourse, adjust the `VS100COMNTOOLS` to your version of MSVS

Comment: In MSVS 8.0 (2005) and MSVS 9.0 (2008) this does not work for C++ projects. Since MSVS 10.0 (2010) it should.

Comment: MSBuild does not support a few projects like SSRS and maybe SSIS. It did not support the SSDT project initially but now does.

Comment: And with experience I have now I'd add that since MSVS 10.0 (2010) it does not always work either. Just calling MSBuild will often use different version than the one that comes with Visual Studio, but I've also seen some strange failures when running external commands even though I believe we did get it to invoke the correct version. `devenv.com` works more reliably.